# Adding Labels in Scientific Notation to Forest Plots Using the metafor package

Tags: r, expression, scientific-notation, r-forestplot, metafor

So I'm doing a meta-analysis using the `meta.for` package in `R`. I am preparing figures for publication in a scientific journal and i would like to add p-values to my forest plots but with scientific annotation formatted as

```
x10-04
```

rather than standard

`e-04`

However the argument `ilab` in the `forest` function does not accept `expression` class objects but only vectors

Here is an example :

```
library(metafor)
data(dat.bcg)

## REM 
res <- rma(ai = tpos, bi = tneg, ci = cpos, di = cneg, data = dat.bcg,
           measure = "RR",
           slab = paste(author, year, sep = ", "), method = "REML")
# MADE UP PVALUES
set.seed(513)
p.vals <- runif(nrow(dat.bcg), 1e-6,0.02)

# Format pvalues so only those bellow 0.01 are scientifically notated
p.vals <- ifelse(p.vals < 0.01, 
                 format(p.vals,digits = 3,scientific = TRUE,trim = TRUE),
                 format(round(p.vals, 2), nsmall=2, trim=TRUE))

## Forest plot
forest(res, ilab = p.vals, ilab.xpos = 3, order = "obs", xlab = "Relative Risk")
```

[image]

I want the scientific notation of the p-values to be formatted as

```
x10-04
```

All the answers to similar questions that i've seen suggest using `expression()` but that gives `Error in cbind(ilab) : cannot create a matrix from type 'expression'` which makes sense because the help file on `forest` specifies that the `ilab` argument should be a vector.

Any ideas on how I can either fix this or work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hacky solution would be to

```
forest.rma <- edit(forest.rma)
```

Go to line 574 and change

```
## line 574
text(ilab.xpos[l], rows, ilab[, l], pos = ilab.pos[l],
```

to

```
text(ilab.xpos[l], rows, parse(text = ilab[, l]), pos = ilab.pos[l],
```

fix your p-values and plot

```
p.vals <- gsub('e(.*)', '~x~10^{"\\1"}', p.vals)
forest(res, ilab = p.vals, ilab.xpos = 3, order = "obs", xlab = "Relative Risk")
```

[image]